# No logro obtener datos de un XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

No se como obtener fácilmente datos dentro de un XML con formato.
Siempre me cuesta demasiado y quiero entender que hago mal.

tengo un archivo XML, obtengo la ruta valida y cargo el documento:

```
$dirXML = "directorio/archivo/xml.xml";
$cont = simplexml_load_file($dirXML);
```

Dicho XML cargado, tiene la siguiente estructura, de donde trato de obtener los rangos `RNG->D` y `RNG->H`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<DTE version="1.0">
    <Documento ID="T15433">
        <TED version="1.0">
            <DD>
                <CAF version="1.0">
                    <DA>
                        <RE>70064202-K</RE>
                        <RS>JUNTA DE ALCALDES PROVIDENCIA LAS CONDES</RS>
                        <TD>39</TD>
                        <RNG>
                            <D>10001</D>
                            <H>20000</H>
                        </RNG>
                        <FA>2021-03-10</FA>
                        <IDK>300</IDK>
                    </DA>
                </CAF>
            </DD>
        </TED>
    </Documento>
</DTE>
```

Hasta ahora solo he tratado de seguir la estructura del XML y mostrar eso, pero solo me saltan errores:

```
var_dump($cont->DTE->Documento->TED->DD->CAF->DA->RNG);
/* Salida:
Notice: Trying to get property 'TED' of non-object...
Notice: Trying to get property 'DD' of non-object...
Notice: Trying to get property 'CAF' of non-object...
Notice: Trying to get property 'DA' of non-object...
Notice: Trying to get property 'RNG' of non-object...
NULL
*/
```

---

Agregando intentos sugeridos por la comunidad:

- `var_dump($cont)`: muestra correctamente el XML.
- `var_dump($cont->DTE->Documento)`: muestra NULL
- Tal y como dice Francisco, con el uso de `string`, funciona, pero me queda la duda de por que con `file` no ???
- `$cont['DTE']['Documento']['TED']['DD']['CAF']['DA']['RNG']; = NULL`

Salida del `var_dump($cont)`:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["D"]=> string(5) "10001" ["H"]=> string(5) "20000" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" } ["Documento"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(6) "T15433" } ["TED"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" } ["DD"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { ["CAF"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" } ["DA"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (6) { ["RE"]=> string(10) "70064202-K" ["RS"]=> string(40) "JUNTA DE ALCALDES PROVIDENCIA LAS CONDES" ["TD"]=> string(2) "39" ["RNG"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (2) { ["D"]=> string(5) "10001" ["H"]=> string(5) "20000" } ["FA"]=> string(10) "2021-03-10" ["IDK"]=> string(3) "300" } } } } } }
```

Comment: si haces el var_dump solo de: $cont->DTE->Documento que te sale?

Comment: Pues deberías hacer el dump del objeto para validar que lo esta leyendo esa es una prioridad de lectura correctamente... no de la lectura del ultimo NODO... valida y me dices...

Comment: puedes agregar el var_dump de $cont?

Comment: El documento es más largo, pero como te dije antes, el var_dump de $cont si devuelve el documento... si quieres te lo muestro por el chat

Comment: ok dale por chat; yo hice esto (pero con string): https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b55R

Comment: No está reconociendo el objeto a partir de `Documento`, ¿qué arroja un **`var_dump($cont->DTE->Documento);`**? Trata de depurar también el resultado en sí mismo con `var_dump($cont);`

Comment: var_dump($cont) muestra correctamente todo el xml. var_dump($cont->DTE->Documento); muestra null, y eso mismo no entiendo porque.

Comment: agrega el resultado del dump de $cont por favor...

Comment: agregada la salida, es lo mismo que obtuviste tu

Comment: ok intenta hacer dump de esto ahora: $cont->Documento

Comment: Ese si da resultado !! por que al tener DTE no ?? esa parte no va o que ?

Comment: por que DTE es tu root y al parecer el objeto $cont contiene el root y no necesitas citarlo... esta bien raro pero me acabo de das cuenta de eso....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por algún motivo `DTE` al ser tu nodo `root` no debes usarlo en el acceso al objeto; desconozco si esto es un bug o que, pero el acceso quedaría así:

```
$cont->Documento->TED->DD->CAF->DA->RNG
```

la lectura de `string` tiene un resultado `objeto` distinto a si lo haces con un `archivo`.

esto es lo que dice la documentación:

**Ejemplo #1 Interpreta un documento XML**

```
<?php
// El fichero test.xml contiene un documento XML con un elemento raíz y, al
// menos, un elemento /[raiz]/titulo.

if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
 
    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Error abriendo test.xml.');
}
?>
```

Este script mostrará, si no hay errores:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [titulo] => Título ejemplo
  ...
)
```

En este punto, se puede seguir recorriendo usando `$xml->titulo` y cualquier otro elemento.

---

**En conclusión:**

como veras en el ejemplo: `$xml->titulo` no se usa el nodo `root` para el acceso a los `sub-objetos`

Comment: Completamente raro que root sea considerado o no... veré si obtengo detalles de esa diferencia, pero gracias por toda la ayuda ;)

Comment: es php... esperaría cualquier cosa...

Comment: Francisco no es un bug. Simplemente cuando se usa SimpleXML el objeto que se obtiene es el root, si analizas el [XML de ejemplo en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/simplexml.examples-basic.php) verás que el root es `peliculas` y si revisas los ejemplos de código verás que para leer los nodos dependientes no se usa `$objeto->peliculas`, sino `$objeto->unHijoDePeliculas` porque `$objeto` apunta a `peliculas`. Para evitar esta confusión una buena práctica es nombrar el objeto que se obtiene con el nombre del root, como de hecho se muestra en los ejemplos del Manual de PHP.

Comment: leiste la conclusión??? lo que decimos el chat del sitio es que la lectura de archivo y la de string no tiene el mismo comportamiento, que seria lo esperado...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes trabajar con `xpath` para identificar el nodo y en base a eso extraer los datos.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    
    $dirXML = "directorio/archivo/xml.xml";
    $cont = simplexml_load_file($dirXML);
    
    $elementos = $cont->xpath('/DTE/Documento/TED/DD/CAF/DA');
    
    foreach($elementos as $dato){
        
        echo $dato->RE;
        echo $dato->RS;
        echo $dato->TD;
        echo $dato->RNG->D;
        echo $dato->RNG->H;
        echo $dato->FA;
        echo $dato->IDK;
    }
    
?>
```

Resultado:

```
70064202-K
JUNTA DE ALCALDES PROVIDENCIA LAS CONDES
39
10001
20000
2021-03-10
300
```

También puede acceder al elemento sin pasar por el foreach `$elementos[0]->RE`